# node-mongo-native and mongo-shell return different results given the same query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Given the next code:

```
  var daysToBeOld = 7;
  var dateOlder = moment().subtract(daysToBeOld, 'days').toDate();

  MongoClient.connect(mongouri, function(err, db) {

    console.log('Filtering pending topics before: %s', dateOlder);

    var conditions = {status: 'pending', updated: {$lt: dateOlder}};

    console.log('Using the next filters: %j', conditions);

    var topicsCol = db.collection('topics');

    topicsCol.find(conditions).toArray(function (err, topics) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }

        console.log("found %j topics", topics);

        callback(err, topics);
      });
  });
```

I get the next console.log results. As you can see the result is an empty array:

```
Filtering pending topics before: Tue Feb 21 2017 15:13:35 GMT+0000 (UTC)
Using the next filters: {"status":"pending","updated":{"$lt":"2017-02-21T15:13:35.191Z"}}
found [] topics
```

If I execute the same query against mongo-shell it returns one document:

I.e:

```
> db.topics.find({"status":"pending","updated":{"$lt":"2017-02-21T15:13:35.191Z"}})
{ "_id" : "076bbbc0-e318-11e6-9375-e94b488c7ad8", "status" : "pending", "text" : "lalalalalla", "topicType" : "Información", "member" : "NoUsuarioForus", "service" : "Limpieza", "idCard" : "", "receiveAnswer" : "1", "toc" : "1", "date" : ISODate("2016-08-31T16:36:45Z"), "sender" : { "name" : "alalalal", "email" : "alalalalala@lalalalal.com" }, "__v" : 0, "deleted" : false, "answered" : true, "firstAnswerTime" : 15614529, "updated" : "2016-02-01T17:28:34.868Z"
```

Why I'm getting no results in the query launched from node-mongo-native?

My node-mongo-native version is 2.2.24.

I've started using mongoose but switched to node-mongo-native to make this query because I was thinking that was an issue with mongoose. Btw I'm going to post my schema if it helps to clarify why it's not working:

topic.js:

```
var mongoose         = require('mongoose');
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
var Schema           = mongoose.Schema;
var uuid             = require('node-uuid');
var xss              = require('xss');

var TopicSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    default: uuid.v1
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    // open: When the message is created first time or not exists
    // pending: The issue has been answered by some employee. Waiting for answer from the customer
    // closed: The issue has been resolved
    enum: ['open', 'closed', 'pending']
  },
  sender: {
    name: String,
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    }
  },
  text: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updated: {
    type: Date
  },
  // If the topic is answered by an user different than creator it will be true
  answered: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  firstAnswerTime: Number,
  centerId: String,
  topicType: String,
  member: String,
  service: String,
  idCard: String,
  receiveAnswer: String,
  toc: String,
  satisfaction: Number,
  deleted: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  }
});

TopicSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

TopicSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.updated = new Date();
  this.text = xss(this.text);
  next();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Topic', TopicSchema);
```

Comment: I have defined my model using mongoose. I'm going to update the question.

Comment: `updated` field is a string and in your application you are querying it as a date, which won't yield anything but when you query it in mongo shell using a string it correctly returns the document.

Comment: Seeing that `updated` field is a string, have you tried querying it as one i.e. changing the variable to `var dateOlder = moment().subtract(daysToBeOld, 'days').toISOString()`?

Comment: Thanks @chridam! It was the format of the date as you said. Thank you so much :) If you submit as an answer I'll accept as a accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the underlying collection, `updated` field is stored as a string and in your application you are querying it as a date, which won't yield anything but when you query it in mongo shell using a string it correctly returns the document.

Seeing that `updated` field is a string, try querying it as one i.e. changing the query variable to

```
var dateOlder = moment().subtract(daysToBeOld, 'days').toISOString();
```